# A library like Python's collections.Counter library for C# -> Getting the difference of values between two dictionary objects in C#

Tags: c#, python

This is how I would create a Dictionary in C#.

```
   Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cheese", 2},
        {"cakes", 1},
        {"milk", 0},
        {"humans", -1}  // This one's for laughs
    };
```

In Python if you have a dictionary like so:

```
from collections import Counter

my_first_dict = {
    "cheese": 1,
    "cakes": 2,
    "milk": 3,
}

my_second_dict = {
    "cheese": 0,
    "cakes": 1,
    "milk": 4,
}

print Counter(my_first_dict) - Counter(my_second_dict)

>>> Counter({'cheese': 1, 'cakes': 1})
```

As you can see, `Counter` is very useful when comparing dictionary objects.

Is there a library in C#, that will allow me to do something similar to this, or do I have to code it from scratch?

Comment: AFAIK there is not such a thing in .NET.

Comment: I'm sure you could somehow with Linq

Comment: Don't use Dictionaries for everything. C# is a strongly typed language. Create a proper data model and use LINQ to query your collections and get whatever results or projections you want.

Comment: Changed the question, I think this would be helpful for future SO users, if it had a more generic title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join the two dictionaries together and then create a new one based on the given operation with only a few lines of code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

var difference = d1.Join(d2, pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Key, (a, b) => new
{
    Key = a.Key,
    Value = a.Value - b.Value,
})
.Where(pair => pair.Value > 0)
.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

There is no system class that you've shown that wraps a dictionary an provides a `-` operator for them, but you can make your own if you want easily enough:

```
public class Counter<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>
{
    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> sequence;
    public Counter(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> sequence)
    {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public static Counter<T> operator -(Counter<T> first, Counter<T> second)
    {
        return new Counter<T>(first.Join(second
            , pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Key, (a, b) =>
                new KeyValuePair<T, int>(a.Key, a.Value - b.Value))
            .Where(pair => pair.Value > 0));
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<T, int>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return sequence.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, you created an entire Counter class.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in functionality like this, but you can use a bit of Linq:

```
Dictionary<string, int> first = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"cheese", 1},
    {"cakes", 2},
    {"milk", 3},
};
Dictionary<string, int> second = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"cheese", 0},
    {"cakes", 1},
    {"milk", 4},
};

var results = 
    (from x in first
     join y in second on x.Key equals y.Key
     where x.Value - y.Value > 0
     select new { x.Key, Value = x.Value - y.Value })
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

// returns a dictionary like { { "cheese", 1 }, { "cakes", 1 } }
```

Comment: The `Where` isn't needed.  If the value is zero negative, that's simply the correct result of subtraction.

Comment: @Servy Well in OP's example, the resulting object doesn't contain a record for "milk". I assume that was the intent here.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes. That was my intent.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thank you for the answer. I got a taste of how awesome C# can be with the syntax you just showed me.

Comment: @Servy because that's how Python's Counter class works. It's a really interesting piece of code :).